# Patching Manifest/Plist to build with different platform-specific settings

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

We are in the process of upgrading our already published native apps available on all the three stores,with a new version developed with **Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova**.

In order to be able to upgrade the app in the stores, we need to publish them specifying the correct versions and correct package-id for each platform.

We need to compile our solution specifying a custom manifest/plist   where we will set the correct version and package.

VisualStudio Tools for Apache Cordova has a general settings for all the platforms:

[image]

Reading the [available documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#NativeConfig), it seems that it is also possible to specify platform-specific configuration files:

> **Android**
> Place the custom AndroidManifest.xml file in
> the res/native/android folder to configure settings such as custom
> intents. Use the generated version of the file in the
> bld/Debug/platforms/android folder after building a Debug
> configuration of the project for Android.
>
> **iOS**
> Place a custom Info.plist file in the res/native/ios/config.xml display name folder
> to override settings like splashscreens or icons. The Info.plist
> filename must be renamed as follows: config.xml display
> name-Info.plist. You can find sample versions of these files in the
> cordova-ios GitHub repository, or you can use the generated version
> for your app from the build folder on your Mac (when using the remote
> agent) under the build number/cordovaApp folder.
>
> **Windows Phone 8**
> Place the custom WMAppManifest.xml file in the
> res/native/wp8/Properties folder. Use the generated version of the
> file in the bld/Debug/platforms/wp8/Properties folder after building
> the project for Windows Phone 8.

We have started our experiment with IOS trying to add a "patched" `XXX-Info.plist`  as stated in the documentation, but we get this error on compile time:

> Automatic provisioning profile selection unavailable: A bundle
> identifier is required for automatic provisioning profile selection.
> Either enter a bundle identifier in the Info.plist, or select a
> provisioning profile to use in the build settings

Removing the XXX-Info.plist, the solutions builds without any problem.
Any hints?

Comment: I'm having the same issue... I'm trying to apply that patch:https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa, but I can't manage to generate and add a working XXX-Info.plist in my project. And the link to the documentation is now dead... Where did you copy your plist from?

Comment: OK, got it working by using the XXX-Info.plist from the generated platform folder. For anyone who had the same issue as me, a better approach is proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32778452/1010492 (uses a plugin to add the missing key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following key to your Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>your.bundle.id.goes.here</string>
```

This bundle id should match the one used when generating your iOS provisioning profile on the iOS Dev Center.

Comment: We found that we were copying a wrong version of plist.