# Patching AndroidManifest.xml is not working on Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: android, visual-studio-cordova

We are in the process of upgrading our already published native Android app available on Google Play store, with a new version developed with **Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova**.

In order to be able to upgrade the app in the store, we need to republish it specifying the correct version and package-id.

As we have a single solution for iOS, Android and WP8, we need to be able to  compile it specifying a custom manifest/plist   where we will set the correct version and package.

Reading the [available documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757053.aspx#NativeConfig), it seems that it is also possible to specify platform-specific configuration files:

> **Android**
>   Place the custom AndroidManifest.xml file in
>   the res/native/android folder to configure settings such as custom
>   intents. Use the generated version of the file in the
>   bld/Debug/platforms/android folder after building a Debug
>   configuration of the project for Android.

As suggested, we have tried to add a different AndroidManifest.xml in the `res/native/android` folder, but the built `apk` still contains and uses the default `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Any hints?

**Note:** follow up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320904/patching-manifest-plist-to-build-with-different-platform-specific-settings) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain fields are overwritten by plugins and the Cordova build process itself. This updated manifest becomes the base that Cordova then augments.

Unfortunately package ID and version are two fields Cordova overwrites. These fields should be modified in config.xml.  You can use the designer or View Code and modify these two attributes under the widget element.

id="my.applicaiton.id" version="1.0.0"

As a side note, an easy way to see whether your custom manifest is getting picked up is to update android:name in AndroidManifest.xml to something different.  When you then build the resulting apk should reflect this new name.

Comment: It seems that the patching on the other two platforms are working fine.Do you know why patching `Plist `and `WMAppManifest.xml` can override package ID and Version without problem? It seems that just Android does not work and has a different behaviour. Is the build different for the Android platform?

Comment: Each platform uses its own native build process, so yes, there can be subtle variations in the way each works.  However, Windows Phone 8 appears to also overwrite the version value at least from the smoke test I just did.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

> Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with
>   precisely that name) in its root directory. The manifest file presents
>   essential information about your app to the Android system,
>   information the system must have before it can run any of the app's
>   code.

So I would think that during the build of the app that Cordova would need to replace the main Manifest file with your device specific version.

Also, would the config.xml file help?
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your answer. Have you tried it? Is it working for you?