# Cordova iOS landscape orientation

Tags: ios, cordova

My Cordova app never rotates to landscape mode when running on iPhone.

I've tried many solutions as putting these lines in the config.xml files:

```
  <preference name="ios-orientation-iphone" value="portrait and landscape" />
  <preference name="ios-orientation-ipad" value="portrait and landscape" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
```

I also put the following line inside the `<platform name="ios">` block:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
```

Then I did the following in my index.js file:

```
        window.shouldRotateToOrientation = function (degrees) {
            return true;
        };
```

Finally, I tried to create a custom plist file in the res/native/ios folder cause I noticed than the generated plist file didn't contain these lines:

```
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
```

I don't know what to do next. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove all of these?  Cordova should allow landscape and portrait orientations by default.

Add only: `<preference name="Orientation" value="default" />` to your config.xml if you'd like to be explicit

Comment: Just make the settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it. The trick was just to put the custom .plist file in the res/native//-Info.plist.

This link gave me the solution: [Tools for Apache Cordova (VS2015): Adding custom entries to *info.plist for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744175/tools-for-apache-cordova-vs2015-adding-custom-entries-to-info-plist-for-ios/32778452#32778452)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a shortcoming of the cordova cli that creates the Xcode project -- it doesn't add those orientation tags.

A while back I had added the following to my config.xml (I'm using the PhoneGap build service currently).

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" mode="replace">
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

There's more info on this blog post: http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/.

---

**Update**: I had a link the `<config-file>` element, but it looks like that element is for plugins (in the plugin.xml file), not for the normal build -- so it won't work.

So... your best bets are:

- To programmatically adding orientation stuff, create a script that finds your .plist file and adds the following block to it if the block isn't there:

  ```
  <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
  <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
  </array>
  ```
- To add it after the platform is added via `cordova platform add ios`, open the .xcodeproj file, go to the project node / General / Deployment info, and check all the orientations for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I tried to do everything you told me but nothing worked. I also tried to reset settings to default but no changes.

It doesn't work both on emulator and iPhone device.

I noticed that the generated .plist file at build time doesn't contain the orientation settings, even when I try to override this file in /res/native/ios.

Any other idea ? Thanks

Comment: I just checked that second link, and it looks like it's specific to plugins, so it won't help you. I've updated my answer -- looks like the options you have are to create a script to add the block to the .plist file OR to manually change the configuration from within Xcode (as @Joerg  mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for this reply. But I forgot to mention that I don't work on Mac OS. I work on Windows using Cordova on Visual Studio. So I m unable to locate the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: Okay, that limits your options even more. The .xcodeproj file should show up in your platforms/ios directory *as a directory* (that's really what it is in OS X as well). But you won't be able to manually make the orientation changes from within Xcode if you're on Windows. Your only option is to add the block I've posted above to your .plist file. Add the block just before the last `</dict></plist>` in the file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Anyway I tried to manually edit all the .plist files I found in my Cordova app directories. Their content is fully erased at runtime and don't take account of my edits. I wonder why this behavior happens because when I target Windows Phone, I just copied basic appxmanifest files and set my own properties and it works well. So, to be clear, your solution would be to make a script in platform/ios to overwrite the .plist content at runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've found a solution. Here's another one that uses build hooks and npm.js to do the work; the benefit is that this should work cross-platform, should you ever do development on linux or OSX. Here's more info about build hooks: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/index.html

1. Add the following to your `config.xml` file:

   ```
   <platform name="ios">
       <hook type="after_prepare" src="iosAfterPrepare.js" />
   </platform>
   ```
2. Create a file named `iosAfterPrepare.js` in the top-level directory and copy in the following (replacing MyProject with the name of your project):

   ```
   // iosAfterPrepare.js
   // Node.js build script run after "cordova ios prepare" (part of cordova build).
   // This adds the various orientations to the plist file for your project.

   module.exports = function (context) {
     var fs    = require('fs'),     // nodejs.org/api/fs.html
         plist = require('plist'),  // www.npmjs.com/package/plist
         // Here you will replace "MyProject" with the name of yours,
         // so that the .plist file can be found
         FILEPATH = 'platforms/ios/MyProject/MyProject-Info.plist',
         xml = fs.readFileSync(FILEPATH, 'utf8'),
         obj = plist.parse(xml);

     obj.UISupportedInterfaceOrientations = [
         "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",
         "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown",
         "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft",
         "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight"
     ];

     xml = plist.build(obj);
     fs.writeFileSync(FILEPATH, xml, { encoding: 'utf8' });

   };
   ```
3. You might need to do call `npm install --save plist` to get the plist module on your machine (it'll complain that it can't find plist).
4. Call:

   ```
   cordova platform rm ios
   cordova platform add ios
   ```

You should see the lines in the .plist file at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in cordova v 7.0.1

### `<preference name="Orientation" value="default" />`

in `config.xml`

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you need to add "gap://*" property into Content Security Policy in your index.html file (two slashed are required).
For example:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:* gap://* tel:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'" />
```

Othewise phone changes orientation only if the user interacts with OS (pressing the front button, showing the notification center with drag down or go to device settings dragging up).

ondeviceready event will neither fire without gap://* value set.

You also need to add cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

from [corvoda-plugin-whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/) description:

> - gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication

Tested on cordova 8.1.2